# Identify column index in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, indexing

I have a *NxM matrix* saved in an **Excel file**. It is easy to identify the rows indexes since they are displayed by the program itself. The columns however are indexed by the letters of the alphabet and I am *not able to recognize the index of the column once the matrix dimensions become too large*. Of course I could count every single column but this is not a practical way to proceed.

So here is my question: **what is a simple way to identify the index of a generic column in Excel?**

My goal would be to **add a specific row and column to my matrix** and the only way I could to do it is by knowing what index the column has (The letters do not help me because I should count all of them until I reach the one that I am interested in).

Comment: How are you inserting data into the matrix? The simplest solution I can think of is to have a header row which contains column values. There are other ways using formulae and vba. Essentially it's a `char` to `int` conversion.

Comment: @gms0ulman The simplest solution is my answer I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Options`. Select `Formulas`. Make sure that under the voice `Working with formulas`, the box `R1C1 reference style` is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula `=COLUMN()` to get the index of the current column. In case you have table with column offset then you can adjust it like `=COLUMN(CurrentColumn)-COLUMN(LastColumn)`.